# Blender Eevee, How do I update indirect lighting before every frame during rendering?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, baking, reflection, lightprobe

I've been making a scene in Eevee where an astronaut is moving down a hallway and he has a reflective visor, however he moves quite far. Probably 10m worth of distance. I made a glossy material and enabled screen space reflections and did everything to make my reflections work, I then added a reflection cubemap (light probe) and it worked perfectly, until the astronaut started to move down the hallway.

I believe it keeps the initial bake and when the astronaut moves far away from the location of the initial bake it doesn't look good.

I tried enabling auto bake, but for some reason that doesn't work when rendering, only when in viewport. I also tried using some code from another website but that also didn't work. Is there some way I could get the cubemap to rebake before every frame whilst rendering?

I could do this manually but that would take an absurd amount of time.

I understand Cycles is probably the better choice for this job but I'm afraid I just don't have the hardware or time to get these renders done in cycles.

Hope I explained it ok, let me know if you need more info.

All the best!

Comment: Why don't you simply parent a real light to your emissive object? This way, you don't have to worry about light probes